# Should I use the ratio test to determine convergence for $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over k\left[1 + \ln^{2}\left(k\right)\right]}$?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to determine whether this is convergent and I was wondering if using the ratio test would be the right way to do it?

${(k)(1+ln^2(k)) \over [k+1]\left[1 + \ln^{2}\left(k+1\right)\right]}$

After this point I'm not sure where to go, so I do not know if I'm doing it right or not... could someone offer me any insight/hints to the right path?

Thank you

Comment: Give the integral test a try.

Comment: The ratio is $1$, so the Ratio Test will be inconclusive.

Comment: [Cauchy's condensation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) will also work.

Comment: thank you both very much! now if I were to use the integral test, would 1/k be an okay function to compare it to?

Comment: @Dimitrios If you are satisfied with my answer, you are free to accept it - if not, let me know what part you are having trouble with and I would be glad to clarify it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine whether the following series convergent?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/725607/determine-whether-the-following-series-convergent)

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT** [The integral test was misapplied (c.f. the comments to this answer). My thanks to Claude Leibovici who's line of inquiry brought this to light.]

Since
$$
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over k\left[1 + \ln^{2}\left(k\right)\right]} \leq {1 \over k\left[1 + \ln^{2}\left(k\right)\right]} \Bigg|_{k=1} + \int_1 ^\infty {1 \over x \left[1 + \ln^{2}\left(x\right)\right]} \mathrm{d} x = 1 + \int_0 ^\infty \frac{1}{1 + u^2} \mathrm{d} u . 
$$
Using that $\int_a ^b \frac{1}{1 + u^2} \mathrm{d} u = \arctan u \Big|_a ^b$, this gives

$$
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over k\left[1 + \ln^{2}\left(k\right)\right]} \leq 1 + \arctan u \, \Big|_{0} ^{b \to \infty} = 1 + \frac{\pi}{2} \approx 2.57079632.
$$

Comment: I have a problem since the numerical evaluation of the sum leads me to a value equal to $2.15989$. Where am I wrong ? Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Hmm... that's interesting! I did not numerically evaluate the sum actually - I proceeded directly as shown in my post above. I also retraced my steps just now, and do not see an error in my thought process. Do you see one, or experience trouble following it? That might suggest a mistake on my part.. otherwise, I am not sure what is the case. Is it possible that your numerical evaluation is flawed (not meant to insult your process at all)?

Comment: I double checked my result and it is OK. Your integrals are OK. Then what ??? Cheers.

Comment: If you sum the first four terms, you already get $\pi/2$

Comment: I think I spot the mistake.. according to the handy reference [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence), I have misappropriated the integral test sloppily and actually $$ \sum_{n=N} ^\infty f(n) \leq f(N) + \int_N ^\infty f(x) \, \mathrm{d} x .$$

Comment: Evaluating for this problem, that gives that the sum is $\leq 1 + \frac{\pi}{2} \approx 2.57079632$.

Comment: That is good ! Thanks.

Comment: Yep, no problem - thanks for noticing it, as I hadn't noticed at all! I updated the answer to reflect this.